# postgresql update a table column based on values stored in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables. I want to update the `emodnet_code` column  values of the table named `2018_01` based on the column `emodnet_type` of another table named `shiptype_emodnet` and using the matching of values of two other columns: column `aisshiptype` from `2018_01` table and column `aisshiptype` from `shyptype_emodnet` table. Query returned successfully but 0 rows affected:

```sql
UPDATE "2018_01"
SET emodnet_code = shiptype_emodnet.emodnet_type
FROM "shiptype_emodnet" 
WHERE '2018_01.aisshiptype' = 'shiptype_emodnet.aisshiptype';
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What does the corresponding `SELECT` return?

Comment: the query returned succesfully but with 0 rows affected and this is not possible. my question is: there is some error in the code?

Comment: Why is this not possible? If the `SELECT` returns 0 rows, there is no data that matches the `WHERE` condition. Check it.

Comment: Obviously it's not "impossible" as it apparently happened to you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing string constants in your WHERE clause, **not** columns. So your where clause:

```
WHERE '2018_01.aisshiptype' = 'shiptype_emodnet.aisshiptype';
```

is always false, because the string literal `'2018_01.aisshiptype'` is never the same as the string literal `'shiptype_emodnet.aisshiptype'`. So your where condition is essentially the same as:

```
where false
```

---

[Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) need to be quoted with double quotes (`"`). Single quotes (`'`) are **only** for [string literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS).

```
UPDATE "2018_01"
  SET emodnet_code = shiptype_emodnet.emodnet_type
FROM "shiptype_emodnet" 
WHERE "2018_01".aisshiptype = shiptype_emodnet.aisshiptype;
```

And you only need the double quotes for columns or tables that use names that are illegal in SQL or were created using double quotes and mixed case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
UPDATE "2018_01" t
SET t.emodnet_code = (SELECT shiptype_emodnet.emodnet_type 
                    FROM shiptype_emodnet 
                    WHERE t.aisshiptype = shiptype_emodnet.aisshiptype
                    Limit 1);
```

You should add `limit 1` for update each row